# Show when $x \notin R(A)$, then $x \in N(A^T)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$. Can we say when $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is not in range of $A$, then it is in the null space of $A$?

My try:

We know that $R(A)$ is a subspace in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ whose dimension is $r \leq m$ and its complement is $N(A^T)$, i.e., $R(A) \bigoplus N(A^T) = \mathbb{R}^{m}$. Therefore, when $x$ is not in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$, it would be in the other one.

Am I right? If so, can you please provide me with other proofs and explanations?

Comment: If $x\in R(A)\oplus N(A^T)$, then $x$ could be in the form $a+b$ for some non-zero $a\in R(A)$ and some non-zero $b\in N(A^T)$. In point of fact, in general the only possible way for a subspace $X$ to contain $\Bbb R^m\setminus V$ for some subspace $V$ is that either $X=\Bbb R^m$ or $V=\Bbb R^m$.

Comment: @Gae. S: Can you please use $R(A)$ or $N(A^T)$ instead of $V$ to explain. Also, can you please let me know if the implication in the title is correct?

Comment: Set theoretic complement is different from additive complement.

Comment: @Sepide No, I cannot, because when I say *in general*, I mean *in general*. And no, it isn't, because of what I have said.

Comment: The statement in the title is false. Take $T(x,y)=(x,0)$. Then $(1,1)$ is not in the range of $T$ but it is also not in the kernel of the transpose of $T$.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy: What condition can I infer when $x \notin R(A)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your question boils down to the following statement.
Let $V$ a vector space and $W_1$ and $W_2$ be two subspaces of $V$. Given:
\begin{equation}
V = W_1 \oplus W_2
\end{equation} For some $v \in V$, if $ v \notin W_1$ does that say anything about $v$ being in $W_2$. The answer is no.

Let us look at one consequence of the direct sum decomposition above. It tells us there exist bases of $W_1$ and $W_2$, let them be $\mathcal{B}_1$ and $\mathcal{B}_2$, such that:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{B} = \mathcal{B}_1 \cup \mathcal{B}_2
\end{equation} where $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for $V$.
Now if an element cannot be written as a linear combination of elements of $\mathcal{B}_1$, does that mean it can be written a linear combination of elements of $\mathcal{B}_2$?

For a simple counter example, take
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{B}_1 = \{b_1,b_2\} \text{ and } \mathcal{B}_2 = \{b_3\}
\end{equation}
Let $v=b_1+b_2+b_3$. As evident, $v \notin W_1$ and $v \notin W_2$.